# heroku git clone issue

Tags: heroku, git-clone

I try to clone one project from heroku, while I run into several issues, help me, thanks very much.

Firstly, I try

$ heroku git:clone myapp  && git clone git@heroku.com:myapp.git

both outputs following messages

---

Cloning from app 'myapp'...
Cloning into myapp...

### ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Bad file number

So, I am using one ssh config file

---

Host heroku.com
Hostname heroku.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

### Port 443

Then using the same command

$ heroku git:clone myapp  && git clone git@heroku.com:myapp.git

both with new output messages

---

Cloning from app 'myapp'...
Cloning into myapp...
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

### Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I am collaborator of the project and I have added the public key into my account, and I have installed heroku-toolbelt.

Comment: Please try to get single question in SO so that it can be answered. Also trying adding detailed log files. Multiple/unclear questions will lead to no response. Consider editing your quesion.

Comment: Please try the git clone with verbose output enabled 'git clone --verbose git@heroku.com:myapp.git'

Comment: @Othrayte Thanks this works!

Answer (score 0):

If any any get this type of error while cloning app from heroku or push or pull

> Failed to connect to git.heroku.com port 443: Network is unreachable

I am just giving it a name as answer.

```
git clone --verbose git@heroku.com:myapp.git
```

As @Othrayte's comment he suggested to use this command to use.

Thanks @Othrayte